# Tridion template builder: Error while opening a Compound template

Tags: tridion

Tridion Template Builder Error

While opening a compound Template from Template Builder, we get the error as

"Could not load file or Assembly Tridion.ContentManager.TemplateTypes Ver 5.3.0.1219.....or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

We are using Tridion R5.3.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was probably due to version mismatch.
We tried using the template builder with Tridion 2011 SP1 and it worked fine.

This shouldn't be a problem henceforth as we are migrating to Tridion 2011 from 5.3

Thanks Everybody.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try uninstalling the template builder and reinstall?

Comment: Also, if you have recently upgraded, or copied templates from another environment - double check that your assemblies are compiles with the correct version of the templating DLLs

Comment: Ok, We will try this and let you know. Thanks for your help.